# Distorted text when exporting as png from Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, png

I'm trying to export text as a png from Illustrator CC, but the text is getting slightly distorted. The lowercase e's look like they have a serif or something:

[image: Distorted type]

I'm required to make art that includes 10pt Helvetica on transparent backgrounds at 96 dpi. The art will be seen on a computer and will be clicked and dragged into another spot onscreen. I have tried expanding the text, and then exporting, but it makes the type look bold. What is the best way to export art with text as a png in this situation?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your PNG export/save settings

Answer (score 2):

3 things:

First, have you tried using the "Save for Web" interface and selecting "Type Optimized" from the dropdown before exporting?

Second, if that doesn't work, make sure your artboard is lined up on whole pixels. Using the artboard tool, select your artboard and look at the info bar to see if the X and Y values are whole numbers (ie, no decimals). Illustrator sometimes has issues with how to resolve anti-aliasing when the artboard is not on whole pixels.

Third, this is the nuclear option, try using Photoshop. PS has much more refined control over small rastered images. When you have the Type Tool active, look at the info bar and you'll see a dropdown box with anti-aliasing options for text. There you can really refine the exact way that Photoshop rasterizes the type with many options. Illustrator only has 2 options - standard "art optimized" (somewhat equivalent to "smooth" in PS), and "Type Optimized" (somewhat similar to "crisp" in PS).